# issue with returned json array

Tags: objective-c, json

I have two questions:

1.I want to load information from json in my app, right now 'NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.news);' doesn't show anything but if I put it in '(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection' it works, can you tell me why?

```
//making request query string
NSString *requestUrl = [NSString
                         stringWithFormat:@"%@jsons/json.php?go=product_info&latitude=%g&longitude=%g&identifire=%@&pid=%ld&externalIPAddress=%@&localIPAddress=%@",
                         BASE_URL,
                         coordinate.latitude,
                         coordinate.longitude,
                         uniqueIdentifier,
                         (long)self.productId,
                         [self getIPAddress],
                         [self getLocalIPAddress]
                         ];



NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:requestUrl];
NSURLRequest *request= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *c=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSLog(@"Array: %@", self.news);



}
//=========================
-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

self.jsonData= [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}
-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData{


[self.jsonData appendData:theData];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{


self.news=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.jsonData options:nil error:nil];



}

-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

UIAlertView *errorView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"download could not be compelete" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dissmiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[errorView show];

}
```

2.I always have warning 'incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending '*void' to parameter of type 'NSJSONreading...'' for this line of code 'self.news=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.jsonData options:nil error:nil];'

self.news is an array I changed it to dictionary but I've got same warning message.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work since when you call that `NSLog` on your `self.news` the parser has not even started to parse any data. The default value for any `ivar` is `nil`, that's why you get nothing.

Regarding that warning, it is due to the fact `NSJSONSerialization` returns an opaque pointer, namely `id`, to a COCOA obj so you have to cast it out to the `news` type to prevent compiler from complaining.

E.g, suppose your `self.news` being a `NSDictionary`

```
self.news = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.jsonData options:nil error:nil];
```

**EDIT**

In your case, given the structure of your JSON response data, you should use a `NSArray` as root object so

```
 self.news = (NSArray *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.jsonData options:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for information about NSLog.
I want to try self.news as a dictionary but how can I access my data I used to use 
'self.topText.text=[[self.news objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"pname"];'  
how can I write it when it become a dictionary? (sorry I am beginner)

Comment: my information is an array that in each element has information about a product like this:
2013-07-04 18:58:29.301 test[18986:11303] Array: (
        {
        cid = 2;
        image = "http://xxx/images/loginlogo.png";
        manual = "";
        movie = "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v";
        pcode = 023942435228;
        pid = 1;
        pname = "example product";
        price = 12;
        qrcode = "";
        sale = 0;
        "sale_percent" = 0;
        text = "here you can find some extra information about this product....
";
    }
)

Comment: In this case your root object is an array, so you should use a `NSArray`. Generally, that's why NSJSONSerialization returns an opaque type since the JSON root object depends on the format of the JSON data you get from the request.

Comment: I need to load information about many products and then show them I have to put them in an Array, what should I do?

Comment: I suggest you to treat your problem by `valueForKeyPath` [apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), in your case something like `NSArray *products = [self.news valueForKeyPath:@"pname"];` should be sufficient

Comment: self.news =(NSArray*) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.data options:nil error:nil];
NSArray *products = [self.news valueForKeyPath:@"pname"];
self.topText.text=[products objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: but I have this error:

2013-07-04 19:56:16.400 test[19176:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1c91deb 0xc03f47 0x22a9 0xf51c7 0xf5232 0x443d5 0x4476f 0x44905 0x4d917 0x1196c 0x1294b 0x23cb5 0x24beb 0x16698 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1217a 0x13ffc 0x1e0d 0x1d35)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Check out `self.data`, it must be `nil` for some reason (but it shouldn't), that's why you got that crash...In the code you posted here that accessor was called `jsonData`, sure it's not a typo?

Comment: you know what's weird for me, after sending request I have no access to received data but in the connectionDidFinishLoading, I copied that code in connectionDidFinishLoading and works well !!!
but I want to continue my code after sending request not in connectionDidFinishLoading method

Comment: There are several ways of getting those values as the parser returns them (delegate, notifications, other object accessors, other kind of hooks, etc.); that depends on your code design and ultimately on how your data is supposed to interact with the rest of the application...